# Adding a unique row count to a SQL 2008 "for xml path" statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

Ok, not sure if this is possible to do..

I have a query that returns just simple records from the database, but formatted out as XML as follows:

```
select name, address, dateCreated, flag
from table
where name = 'test'
for xml path('row'), root('rows')
```

ok, no problems, and I get the XML as desired:

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <name>jddjdjd</name>
    <address>dkdkdkdkdkd</address>
    .. and so on...
  </row>
</rows>
```

***BUT WHAT I AM TRYING TO FIND OUT IS***

If I can have the XML return as follows:

```
<rows>
  <row id='@@rowcount'>
    <name>jddjdjd</name>
    <address>dkdkdkdkdkd</address>
    .. and so on...
  </row>
</rows>
```

As you can see, I really could do with the  node returning with an attribute of say a @@rowcount or even a field from the select statement (not sure if that is possible!!)

Any help much appreciated!!!
David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alias `@@rowcount` to `'@id'`, like:

```
declare @t table (name varchar(25))

insert @t (name) values ('jddjdjd')

select  @@rowcount as '@id'
,       name
from    @t
for xml path('row'), root('rows')
```

This prints:

```
<rows>
    <row id="1">
        <name>jddjdjd</name>
    </row>
</rows>
```

However, I'm not sure it's clearly defined what `@@rowcount` means at the point where it gets turned into an attribute.

Comment: Hey thanks!! wow that was really a DOH!! moment on my side.. I forgot you can simply add an alias in the form of xxx as "@id" to create the attribute.

Comment: Sorry in addition...  as for the @@rowcount, it was needed just to provide a sequence - I am using www.dhtmlx.com data grids and it needs some sort of unique sequence for each row.. obviously in this case I just needed a running sequence, however of course a record id etc could be used..  many thanks again for responding, very appreciated.